# Is the following space finite-dimensional?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is the following space finite-dimensional?

$$V=\left\{f(t):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\mid f(0)=f'(0)=0, \int_0^1 \left(f''(u)\right)^2 \,du < \infty \right\}$$

This question is largely related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477587/rkhs-why-kernel-int-x-u-t-u-u-does-not-generate-complete-space). After much thought, I tried to show the space $V$ is finite-dimensional with basis $1,t,t^2,t^3$  (even though it just does not look like one).

I considered that

$$f(t) = f(0) + f'(0)t + \int_0^t (t-u) f''(u) \,du$$

and failed to recognize the coefficients for $t^2$ and $t^3$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $1$ and $t$ are not even in your space. (But all $t^n$ for $n\ge2$ are).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Typo, meant to exclude those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The functions $t^2, t^3, t^4, \dots$ all belong to $V$ and are linearly independent.

Comment: Also, when defining $V$ you should specify what regularity properties elements of $V$ must satisfy - i.e do you assume $f$ is twice continuously differentiable? smooth?

Answer (score 1):

No.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ define $f_\lambda : [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ as $f_\lambda(x) = e^{\lambda x} - \lambda x  - 1$, $x \in [0,1]$.

You can check that $\Big\{f_\lambda : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\Big\} \subseteq V$ and that it is linearly independent.